# How to handle inherent missing data in constructed lagging indicators?

Tags: feature-engineering, missing-data

I have a dataset of sports statistics from over the course of several seasons, and I want to incorporate some lagging features for a deep learning time series model. Specifically, I want to generate some features that track certain statistics over the previous `n` games (likely for `n=2,3,4`, but I want to write a function that lets me vary `n`). The problem is that, for example, I cannot generate a value for the `n=4` case on a team that has only played 3 games--there is no previous 4th game to derive any stats from. Is there a standard way of dealing with this kind of missing data besides truncating the dataset to start from the `n+1`th game (thus guaranteeing `n` previous games)?